# PYTHON: cat-ing a remote file via SSH, WHILE SSH tunnel is open

Tags: python, ssh, cat

I must say that I haven't coded seriously since university, latest in '92... 
Since then I've just done some simple VB, so no real coding :)
I am trying to get some python coding done so that I am sending a remote command over SSH and I retrieve the output. Basically I am catting a text file and I am retrieving the contents of the file.

I have seen various methods to do this via SSH, using an ip address, port, key, etc, while opening the tunnel.
Yet, in my case, I have to manipulate the tunnel via some special server control, with web access, invoking Ajax commands, etc.

Relevant here is to just say that I have the python code to open and close the tunnels. What I need is to insert a simple snippet of code to execute a cat and to retrieve the output.

Can someone enlighten me on how that can be done? I don't need elevated access for the command, of course.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. 
I am using python 3.6.4.

TIA

Comment: I've figured out how to do it... Please consider this thread closed.